# Google Play Billing Library 1.0 (2017) - Is it easier to hack?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, in-app-billing, cracking, play-billing-library

Up until now we were using the in app purchaces api using the IabHelper classes that Google was giving in the form of raw code so that we could "rewrite" it and make it difficult for a hacker to reverse engineer it, trace the code and remove it and then upload the app in the black market with everything for free.

Now Google has released the Billing Library with very easy to trace methods and callbacks. Right away I'm wondering what that means for the safety of our apps because I think it's not that good. Can someone explain what Google is thinking with this and how we can still ensure that the app will not be easy to hack?

---

**ΝΟΤΕ**

I'm aware that it's impossible to make an app hackproof. We can just make it more difficult to hack so that the average person can't do it. My question is about whether using the BillingApi from a library makes it easier to hack than the previous approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't be sure what your app isn't hacked. It's only a matter of time.
I suppose all time that my app is hacked and I don't allow do any purchases if root was found.
I suggest you see the [Google SafetyNet helper docs](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Good link from Dima!

The library mostly does integration with Play billing. There should be an additional logic in your app to protect it against hackers.

I also recommend checking [Security Best Practices](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html) from Google Play billing team.